# How to convert a set of point coordinates from a concave hull into a polygon in R?

Tags: r, maps, coordinates, polygon

I have an `alphahull::ashape()` result that I need to convert with `spatstat::owin()` for subsequent spatial analyses. Is there an elegant solution how to order the points from the concave hull and convert the shape to an `owin` object or any `Spatial*` object? With ordered points in a hypothetical matrix `coords` the polygon is defined as:

```
geo.owin=try(owin(poly=list(x=coords[,1],y=coords[,2])),silent=T)
if(class(geo.owin)=="try-error") geo.owin=owin(poly=list(x=rev(coords[,1]),y=rev(coords[,2])))
```

This is not possible. The `ashape()$edges` matrix contains coordinates of points that can be drawn to look like a polygon and the matrix is provided here. However, the points are not ordered as demonstrated with different plotting colors and directions of arrows.

```
# data
okraj = matrix(c(23.8808, 18.0106, 23.8808, 1.8265, 1.8266, 1.8265, 18.0106, 39.5352, 39.5352, 39.5352, 13.5519, 27.9675, 3.8102, 4.8269, 8.8236, 52.7248, 45.3385, 52.7248, 50.9600, 50.9600, 50.9600, 45.3385, 39.9042, 39.9042, 39.9042, 49.1204, 41.8421, 47.1450, 44.9423, 46.0246, 13.5519, 27.9675, 32.1116, 1.8266, 4.5644, 3.8102, 17.5557, 39.5840, 32.1116, 29.2158, 4.5644, 29.2158, 4.8269, 8.8236, 17.5557, 49.1204, 41.8421, 41.3710, 50.9600, 49.8638, 47.1450, 45.5063, 39.8987, 41.3710, 40.0750, 49.8638), ncol=4, dimnames=list(NULL,c("x1","y1","x2","y2")))

# draw polygon from arrows
farby=colorRampPalette(c("lightblue","black"))(nrow(okraj))
plot(0,type="n",xlim=range(okraj[,c(1,3)]),ylim=range(okraj[,c(2,4)]),xlab="",ylab="")
for(i in 1:nrow(okraj)){
    arrows(okraj[i,"x1"],okraj[i,"y1"],okraj[i,"x2"],okraj[i,"y2"],col=farby[i],length=.1,lwd=2)
}
```

[image: Concave hull with unordered points]

The search through other questions returned solutions for [ordered points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620373/spatialpolygons-creating-a-set-of-polygons-in-r-from-coordinates), [convex not concave shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606512/create-convex-hull-polygon-from-points-and-save-as-shapefile), solutions in [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392072/how-to-draw-a-polygon-from-a-set-of-unordered-points), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326068/create-closed-polygon-from-boundary-points) and [Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989100/sort-points-in-clockwise-order) languages. My current code searches for connected points across the matrix and uses `if()` conditions for every problem I ran into in interpreting the alpha shape edge coordinates (pardon the naive coding).

```
# function finding a row, which contains the connecting data
find.connection=function(bod, temp){
    # test whether a connection exists in the first set of point coordinates
    riadok1=ifelse(length(which(temp[,1]==bod[1]))==0,NA,which(temp[,1]==bod[1]))
    riadok2=ifelse(length(which(temp[,2]==bod[2]))==0,NA,which(temp[,2]==bod[2]))
    # test for a connection in the second set of coordinates
    if(is.na(riadok1)){
        riadok1=ifelse(length(which(temp[,3]==bod[1]))==0,NA,which(temp[,3]==bod[1]))
        riadok2=ifelse(length(which(temp[,4]==bod[2]))==0,NA,which(temp[,4]==bod[2]))
    }
    # check multiple values in x or y coordinates and select a row where both occur
    if(riadok1==riadok2){
        riadok=riadok1
    } else {
        riadky1=ifelse(length(which(temp[,3]==bod[1]))==0,NA,which(temp[,3]==bod[1]))
        riadky2=ifelse(length(which(temp[,4]==bod[2]))==0,NA,which(temp[,4]==bod[2]))
        riadok=intersect(riadky1,riadky2)
    }
    return(riadok)
}

# setting up the variable with ordered points
coords=c(okraj[1,c("x2","y2")])
coords=rbind(coords,c(okraj[1,c("x1","y1")]))

# current working point and a matrix subset, in which to search for a connection
bod=okraj[1,1:2]
temp=okraj[-1,]

# consecutively search for connecting points
for(j in 1:nrow(okraj)){

    if(any(is.na(match(bod,temp)))){
        message(paste("Problem with: ", bod,", row: ",j ))
        next
    }

    bod2=NA # next ordered point
    smer=0 # controls the set of coordinates to use for a connection

    for(x in 1:2){
        riadok=find.connection(bod=bod,temp=temp)
        # my solution to the current crash point can be implemented here
        if(is.na(riadok)) bod2=NA
        # select correct value for the connecting point from the two sets of coordinates
        else bod2=temp[riadok,c(x+smer,x+smer+1)]
        if(all(bod==bod2)) bod2=temp[riadok,c(x+2,x+3)]
        if(any(is.na(bod2))){
            smer=1
            next
        } else { break }
    }

    # store the connecting point and move to the next
    coords=rbind(coords,bod2)
    bod=bod2

    # caveats for the last row in the matrix
    if(!is.null(dim(temp))) temp = temp[-riadok,]
    if(is.null(dim(temp))){
        if(all(coords[1,]==coords[nrow(coords),])){
            break
        }
        if(which(temp==bod[1])==1){
            coords=rbind(coords,temp[3:4])
            break
        } else { 
            coords=rbind(coords,temp[1:2])
            break
        }
    }
}
```

It works for some datasets. Here, the sample dataset contains an endpoint `okraj[8,3:4]` that does not connect to anything else in the matrix and the code crashes. My solution would be to skip the row and try again with previous point.

```
if(is.na(riadok)){
    bod2=NA
    temp=temp[-riadok,]
    bod=coords[nrow(coords),]
    next
}
```

However, the solution requires dropping a row of data, which is wrong. Your help with a systematic solution to converting an alpha shape to a mapped object would be very appreciated.

### Edit:

A question about [removing holes from polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338036/remove-holes-in-polygon) received an answer from @Spacedman using `rgeos` routines. How could it help to resolve my problem with unordered points from the example herein?