# How to autocreate a polygon that includes some given points and exclude some given points

Tags: algorithm

I have 3 shapes like in the picture.

I want to auto-create a polygon that includes 2 shapes but excludes another shape. The coordinates of the points of all shapes are given.

Can anyone help me to develop an algorithm for that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I think your question is too broad. Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe I can clarify this question a bit. I want to do this with JavaScript.
My approach is to create a polygon around all figures.
I found a way to do this here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287928/algorithm-to-create-a-polygon-from-points

Then I create a polygon around the figure that shouldn't be included.

I then somehow subtract this polygon from the first one.

But I don't know how to subtract one polygon from the other in Javascript.

Comment: The points outside the shapes look quite arbitrary. Should those be randomly chosen? Should the number of points be randomly chosen? Is the distance from the shapes randomly chosen? Are the shapes convex? It would be good if you could (1) provide more precise specifications and (2) include the code you already have to determine a polygon that surrounds the three shapes.

Comment: Perhaps start by defining a line between each pair of shapes in different regions (one is included and one excluded). If these lines intersect and form a polygon, you're done. Otherwise add lines as needed.

Comment: Given, you are trying to implement this in a specific programming language, you need to provide the expected [mre]. We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output. 
**DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.